# How to query for int and float elements in lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I'm using Lucene 5.3.1 to build up an index each time my eclipse application loads a project.
My index stores numerical information of the type Long and Double.
For indexing I use the fields

```
org.apache.lucene.document.LongField
```

and

```
org.apache.lucene.document.DoubleField
```

Simplified example:

```
final long valueL =...;

final double valueD =...;

new LongField(VALUE, valueL, Field.Store.YES) 

new LongField(VALUE, valueD, Field.Store.YES)
```

If I want to search(NumericRangeQuery) for numeric values bigger than n, the result only takes elements of the index into account which are from the same type as n.
E.g.
If n is Double I only receive Double elements from the index and all Long elements are ignored.

```
"n > 2.1"   -->   (+VALUE:{2.1 TO *})
```

Returns:

```
3.4

2.1
```

But not

```
5
```

And so on.

Is there a way to get Long and Double results in one query?

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
(+VALUE:{2.1 TO *} +VALUE:{2 TO *})
```

Comment: Hello Amey, Thank you for your answer. I´ll try this approach. Tank you!

Comment: this guarantees the all result but not in order!